# pip thinks it needs to be updated when it does not

Tags: python, pip

My installation of pip seems to be convinced it is out of date:

```
$ sudo pip install editable .
<my stuff gets installed>
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /home/wash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ python --version
Python 2.7.11+
```

I am running Debian 8.0. I've tried running `pip install --upgrade pip` as it has requested.

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache and then trying to update?

Comment: Nope. Where can I find the documentation on how to do that?

Comment: #sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
 try running this as root and then try to update

Comment: have you tried `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: `pip --version` -> check `sudo pip --version` - most likely 'from' path will differ.

Comment: Rogalski, yep, that was the issue. Different version for root and me. Thanks